# LabVIEW: clear all the elements in combobox during runtime

Tags: combobox, labview

I have a combobox which has an array of Strings such as "Alice", "Bob",and "Charlie". After user presses the ok button I want to remove all the elements in the combobox. How do I do this during run time ? All I know is to manually right click on the combobox and remove its element one by one.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Settings String[] to an empty array will clear the strings stored in the Combobox, but will not clear the active value visible on the front panel terminal. To clear that as well, use the "Value" property with a blank string.

Here's a snippet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After having tried many ways this does clear elements but the first element is not removed completely.

[image]

Comment: See my solution below, you're close but missing one piece. Also, as others have pointed out to you - avoid answering your own questions. Put any attempts you've made into your initial question and not as an answer.

Comment: @shmicah it's fine to answer your own question if you actually have found a solution to it, but not (as you say) as a means of adding more information.

Comment: I should've been more clear, the keyword I was going for was "attempts" :) Thanks for the clarification though, still learning here